# Comparison between Ido, Esperanto and French

Tags: french, constructed-language, esperanto

I read somewhere this assertion:

> Ido is a try to make Esperanto looking more like French.

Can someone explain me in which extend Ido could be closer than French than Esperanto, in which fields?

(I didn't start Ido courses yet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The design of Ido indeed intends to make it more similar to modern Romance languages (so French is a fair—but may be polemic—pick).

This includes phonology (abolishing the letter ĥ), derivation using Romance suffixes, introduction of more "international" words (hospitalo for malsanulejo, olda for maljuna or malnova).

Ido failed community-wise: it wasn't the next version of Esperanto everyone wanted to adopt. For fans of more naturalistic international languages, (IALA) Interlingua is the choice for a contender of Esperanto.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Why a "polemic" pick?

Comment: @Quidam: Louis Couturat, the main proponent of the Ido reforms, was a French national. The polemic is that he wanted to make Esperanto to be more similar to his native tongue.

Comment: But how? What did he did linguistically to achieve that?

Comment: For a starter on Ido, look here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ido_language and at the references incuded.